Fusion NetworkRigidbody blocks collisions for trigger
I want to have an interactable object with a Rigidbody, so I need to have NetworkRigidbody. But when I add this component, all collisions for trigger (child) are not getting called for client. Only host gets those calls.
Parent Object:

Object with the script:

Item detecting collisions, only collides with local player:
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    a.Indicator.SetActive(true);
}
private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    a.Indicator.SetActive(false);
}


OnTriggerEnter / OnTriggerExit are not reliable in Fusion. This is because these are Unity methods that are called once a frame, where Fusion's resimulations on clients can cause multiple physics simulations in a single Unity frame.
The OnTriggerStay callback does work properly however, and if you need the explicit "enter"/"exit" functions, you can use it (along with a [Networked] variable) to make your own callbacks.

Ok so I tried ontriggerstay, but it does not work as well

i could make host catch these events, but I don't like the fact that everything needs to go over the internet. I would sleep better if I could just make all of these detects on client

The host has to catch all events because only the host has authority over the objects. If you want clients to have authority over their own objects, you have to use shared mode (but you lose cheat protection)

Ok thank you for your help. I'll just make host catch all events.
